# How to create a command to insert a string, but possibly ignore white space before the command?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I would like to define a switch that shows additional comments in some text (containing formulas). As you can see below by setting `showString` to `true`, this works well. However, when I set it to `false`, there is some leftover space before the full stop. I tried to "ignore" it by using `\ignorespaces`, but that's still contains the one blank from after the word "text". How can this be avoided?

One solution would be to insert a space before `#1` in `\mystring` and use "This is just some text\mystring{here}" in the example (so removing the space before the command). Is there a more elegant solution?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newboolean{showString}
\setboolean{showString}{false}% use true/false
\newcommand*{\mystring}[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{showString}}{\text{\bfseries #1}}{\ignorespaces}}

\begin{document}
This is just some text \mystring{here}.

\begin{align*}
  a=b\tag*{\mystring{here}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try putting `\unskip` at the beginning of the "false" condition to get rid of a space already input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
\newcommand*{\mystring}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{showString}}{\text{\bfseries #1}}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}}
```